TRUC transactions (version = 3) general availability
Given that "2 package RBF" and "V3 transactions" are merged in the main branch, which release TRUC transactions would be available? Thank you!
Relevant PRs:
https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/28984
https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/29496

The pull request doc: use TRUC instead of v3 and add release note #30272 states that the TRUC Policy will be live in v28.0 and adds release notes to that effect.
